# Сервер не отправляет страницу, либо отправляет почти пустую, без основных данных. Python

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Хотел сделать парсер интернет магазинов, который парсит цены и регулярно их обновляет. Какие-то магазины отправляют мне страницу, где самой важной информации просто нету, а от некоторых данные вообще не приходят. Некоторые сайты мне даже удаётся парсить, но стоит запустить бесконечный цикл с парсером, как уже через секунду вылетает ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, такое действительно может быть. Вот основные причины, и как их решать:
`1.` Сайт не доступен в вашей стране: Сервер банально запрещает сайт всем пользователям из этой страны. Он может либо вообще не давать никаких данных,  либо отправить страницу с сообщением о заблокированной стране. В таком случае вы можете воспользоваться VPN.
`2.` Неправильный `user-agent`: Если вы отправляете запрос стандартной библиотекой `Python requests`, и кроме URL-адреса в параметрах больше ничего не указываете, то скорее всего страница будет другой, нежели чем той, что вы видите в браузере.

```
import requests


url = 'http://site.do/index.html'
headers = {
'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
} # устанавливаем user-agent


r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Если вы его не укажете, то при запросе так и будет написано: "Запрос отправляет программа `python-requests`". Вы также можете воспользоваться библиотекой fake_useragent ([документация](https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/)). Однако  если вы захотите использовать эту библиотеку, то следует увеличить тайм-аут между запросами (частые запросы с разными `user-agent`-ами могут принять как DoS-атаку.)
`3.` Увеличить тайм-аут. Об этом уже сказано в предыдущем пункте.
`4.` Страница не подгружается скриптами. Сейчас проясню одно важное различие:

```
# Не уходим от предыдущего кода
pageText = r.text # Исходный текст страницы, не подгружаемый скриптами 
# скриптами из <script></script>. PHP код исполняется, т. к. это серверный язык программирования
pageContent = r.content # Контент страницы, подгруженный скриптами
```

Comment: `r.content` - это тот же `r.text`, просто в виде байтов. А в `text` уже строка, полученная из `content`. requests ничего не знает про скрипты. Для скриптов есть requests-html (пример https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5f333adc169490c9d3d031f929f00c3a9e222ed9/requests_html__examples/coronavirus_monitor_ru__statistika.py#L13), либо использовать движок javascript, например, через selenium

Comment: Еще у меня было такое, что сайт работает исключительно на HTTP версии 2, а requests умеет только в версию 1.1, из-за чего парсер не работал. Приходилось использовать другую библиотеку для отправки запросов (нашел: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5f333adc169490c9d3d031f929f00c3a9e222ed9/html_parsing/http_v2.0__maxmaster_ru__hyper_example.py#L8)

Comment: С PHP какая-то фигня... Код сайта может внутри HTML иметь блоки на PHP, но эти блоки будут выполнены на серверной стороне и в ответе не придут. Максимум, в `<script>` будет javascript, который браузер понимает, поэтому может выполнять на стороне клиента. Поэтому, некоторые сайты сложнее парсить - они данные не сразу возвращают в HTML, а рендерят на клиенте через javascript